# Using RTMP or RTSP protocol in C#

Tags: c#, .net, video-streaming, video-capture, video-encoding

Do you know any library that allows me to send from C# an encoded audio/video stream to a streaming server using RTMP or RTSP communication protocol ?

Comment: You can use my library for this!

http://net7mma.codeplex.com/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp

Answer (score 2):

http://www.streamcoders.com/ looks nice.

**RTSP.NET**

> Is a RFC 2326 compliant software stack for the Microsoft .NET framework. You can use it from any .NET-compatible programming language, such as C#, VB.NET or C++/CLI.

- TCP Interleaving
- Unicast UDP
- Multicast UDP
- RTSP over HTTP
- Polymorphic content (XML, SDP, custom)
- Transactional layer (based on request-response model)

Comment: And price of it is nice also, indeed. ;)

Answer (score 2):

As per [this link](http://www.streamcoders.com/products/rtpnet.html). RTP.NET is no longer a separate product of Streamcoders.
The full functionality of RTP.NET plus additional features are included in [MediaSuite.NET](http://www.streamcoders.com/products/msnet.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this library: http://www.broccoliproducts.com/softnotebook/rtmpclient/rtmpclient.php

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with RTSP.

Comment: Not the "OR" in the question, its not "AND"

Comment: Just though it was worth mentioning for the next guy who needs an RTSP client!!