# Is there such a RTSP Ping?

Tags: c#, winforms, network-programming, rtsp

I am currently working on a WinForm app to stream videos from IP camera using the RTSP protocol in C#. Everything worked fine. Part of the requirement for the app includes a function to check whether the IP camera is online or not.

So I did a ping function using the System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping class to ping the IP camera. Say if the RTSP url of the camera is as follows rtsp://**[CAMERA IP]**:554/Master0-RTSP/1.0, I would only need to extract the **[CAMERA IP]** part and use the Ping class to see if the camera is online or not by using its IP.

Initially, it works until an issue came, say if one to enter an IP which may not be the intended IP Camera (say an IP of a computer) the ping function would still work if the entered IP of the entered device is online.

I tried to search for something like a RTSP ping but could not find one. Was hoping for any advices or opinions on this matter. Any example in C# are greatly appreciated. Thank you for your kind attention.

Answer (score 2):

`OPTIONS` can possibly work but the standard specifies the correct way is through using the`GET_PARAMETER`.

RFC2326 outlines that clearly

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt

10.8 GET_PARAMETER

The GET_PARAMETER request retrieves the value of a parameter of a
   presentation or stream specified in the URI. The content of the reply
   and response is left to the implementation. GET_PARAMETER with no
   entity body may be used to test client or server liveness ("ping").

While `GET_PARAMETER` may not be supported by the server there is no way to tell how that server will react to the `OPTIONS` request which does not even require a sessionID. Therefor it cannot be guaranteed it will keep your existing session alive.

This is clear from reading the same RFC about the `OPTIONS` request

10.1 OPTIONS

The behavior is equivalent to that described in [H9.2]. An OPTIONS
   request may be issued at any time, e.g., if the client is about to
   try a nonstandard request. It does not influence server state.

Example:

```
 C->S:  OPTIONS * RTSP/1.0
        CSeq: 1
        Require: implicit-play
        Proxy-Require: gzipped-messages

 S->C:  RTSP/1.0 200 OK
        CSeq: 1
        Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE
```

Note that these are necessarily fictional features (one would hope
   that we would not purposefully overlook a truly useful feature just
   so that we could have a strong example in this section).

If GET_PARAMETER is not supported then you would issue a PLAY request with the SessionId of the session you want to keep alive.

This should work even if OPTIONS doesn't as PLAY honors the Session ID and if you are already playing there is no adverse effect.

For the C# RtspClient see my project @ https://net7mma.codeplex.com/

And the article on CodeProject @ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp

Comment: As you can see no SessionId is required in the options.. this may work but it is NOT STANDARD!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RTSPClientSharp](https://github.com/BogdanovKirill/RtspClientSharp) and do something like this:

```
public static async Task TestRTSPConnection(string rtspAddress, string user, string password)
{
        var serverUri = new Uri(rtspAddress);
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);

        var connectionParameters = new ConnectionParameters(serverUri, credentials);
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var connectTask = ConnectAsync(connectionParameters, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        if (await Task.WhenAny(connectTask, Task.Delay(15000 /*timeout*/)) == connectTask)
        {
            if (!connectTask.Result)
            {
                logger.Warn("Connection refused - check username and password");
            }

            logger.Info("Connection test completed");
        }
        else 
        {
            logger.Warn("Connection timed out - check username and password");
        }
    }

    private static async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(ConnectionParameters connectionParameters, CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var rtspClient = new RtspClient(connectionParameters))
            {
                rtspClient.FrameReceived +=
                    (sender, frame) => logger.Info($"New frame {frame.Timestamp}: {frame.GetType().Name}");

                while (true)
                {
                    logger.Info("Connecting...");

                    try
                    {
                        await rtspClient.ConnectAsync(token);
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        logger.Info("Finishing test before connection could be established. Check credentials");
                        return false;
                    }
                    catch (RtspClientException e)
                    {
                        logger.Error($"{e.Message}: {e.InnerException?.Message}");
                        return false;
                    }

                    logger.Info("Connected - camera is online");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It works for me pretty well if you just care about pinging and if the camera is online or not. Also timeout happens when credentials are incorrect. You get direct failure if port is not exposed or connection is refused.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ICMP` ping, you might want to keep a helper `RTSP` session without video/audio RTP streams, checking good standing of socket connection and sending `OPTIONS` or `DESCRIBE` command on a regular basis, e.g. once a minute, in order to see if the device is responsive.

Some suggest using `GET_PARAMETER` instead of options, however this is inferior method. `OPTIONS` is mandatory, `GET_PARAMETER` is not. Both serve different purpose. Both have small server side execution expense. `OPTIONS` is clearly the better of the two.

> Some servers may not support setting stream parameters and thus not support GET_PARAMETER and SET_PARAMETER.

Comment: That is incorrect. You would utilize the `GET_PARAMETER` method.

Comment: No, I would utilize `OPTIONS` because it is the right way. And you will soon find a server which does not support `GET_PARAMETER`.

Comment: Just because the server does not support it doesn't mean anything...  See my answer above.

Comment: Not right. `OPTIONS` is the mandatory command, while `GET_PARAMETER` is optional, see RFC. RFC just suggest that `GET_PARAMETER` **might** be used for pinging, but it is not the best suggestion.

Comment: Read the RFC the same way you told me... I actually implemented my own so server so thank you very much! I posted the section from the RFC in my answer... It clearly says `OPTIONS` it does not flush state or otherwise and the SessionId is not required in the options request buddy!

Comment: You implemented your own IP camera? Good for you.

Comment: Actually a entire RtspServer which could be located on the firmware of a camera or otherwise... And actually I have worked on camera firmware before... it's not my fault you can't read the RFC!

Comment: Read what? I have a camera that drops RTSP session on unrecognized command. What's your suggestion for this? Trash it out? My method works for any RTSP server, yours is not. Good luck.

Comment: Your does not!!! Read the RFC.. if it works its NOT STANDARD... there is only 1 way to read the RFC dude... take it how you want it! Good Day!

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, you would do what my clients do. Send the options to get the supported methods, after PLAY is issued to perform a keep alive if GET_PARAMETER is supported you would issue that, if not then you would issue a duplicate PLAY request. This is standard and works with all cameras which are standards compliant.

Comment: Thanks for the entertainment guys, priceless. If implementors are not consistent then why not try both methods, if one succeeds then you got a successful ping. Thanks for the tip on PLAY as a server keep alive, that's a great idea which I forgot about after reading the spec a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding RTSP in C# see this thread [Using RTMP or RTSP protocol in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238592/using-rtmp-or-rtsp-protocol-in-c-sharp)

Regarding Ping ... you can implement is as DESCRIBE operation ... but pay attention do not make it too frequently, the device should be affected.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt

Comment: Again incorrect, you would utilize the `GET_PARAMETER`... try reading the standard you are linking to.

Comment: And this is mainly because the `DESCRIBE` request does not require an ID