# how to confirm a ping reply is from an RTSP camera

Tags: c#, rtsp

I am currently working on a window form application in C#. Part of my application requires that the connected IP camera should reply to the ping request but I want to make sure that the device is surely a camera as  any other network device can also reply to my ping request if the IP of camera is mistakenly allotted that device. 
I know that there are certain requests in RTSP like options, Get_parameters, Describe but pardon my ignorance, I am a newbie in Coding and I dont know how to implement these requests in c#.Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Forget the Ping. By far not every Camera will support ICMP. Dig into the respective [RFC Documents](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7826) or look for an existing RTSP lib.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/13830399/982149

Comment: ^^ MInd: The linked answer refers to version 1 (RFC 2326) which is obsoleted by the RFC 7826 (version 2) that I linked earlier. In the latter, the cited paragraph _"GET_PARAMETER with no entity body may be used to test client or server liveness ("ping")."_ seems to have been dropped.